# How to use "def" with strings

Tags: python, python-3.3, function

I'm relatively new to programming so I just recently got started with experimenting with "def" in python. This is my code and its keeps on telling me the first name hasn't been defined.

```
def name(first, last):
    first = str(first)
    last = str(last)
    first = first.upper
    last = last,upper
    print("HELLO", first, last)
```

I then run the program and i write a name like

> > > name(bob, robert)
> > >       and then it would tell me that "bob" hasn't been defined

Comment: To preempt the next two bugs: `first.upper` needs method call parentheses, and `last,upper` is a tuple instead of a method call because you hit the comma key instead of the period.

Answer (score 4):

You should quote them (using `'` or `"`) if you mean string literals:

```
name('bob', 'robert')
```

---

Beside that, the code need a fix.

```
def name(first, last):
    first = str(first)
    last = str(last)
    first = first.upper() # Append `()` to call `upper` method.
    last = last.upper()   # Replaced `,` with `.`.
    print("HELLO", first, last)
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a difference between a variable and a string. A variable is a slot in memory already allocated with a data (string, number, structure...) When you write `robert` without quotes, Python will search this variable already instancied with this name.

Here it doesn't exists, since you don't write `robert = 'something'`. If you want to pass a string directly, you just have to write it, surronding by quotes (or triple quotes if it's on multiple lines).

What you want to achieve is calling your `name` function like this:

```
def name(first, last):
    first = str(first)
    last = str(last)
    first = first.upper
    last = last,upper
    print("HELLO %s %s" % (first, last))

name('bob', 'robert') # Will print "HELLO bob robert"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    def name(first, last):
        first = str(first)
        last = str(last)
        first = first.upper()
        last = last.upper()
        print("HELLO", first, last)
    name("bob","robert")
```

1.str-objects has upper-method, but to call it and get result u have to add "()" after the name of method - because you get link to object-method - not to string in upper case...
2.in calling name(bob,robert) - you put the arguments, which are undefined variables..
to do this u have to define these variables before calling, f.g:

```
    bob = "bob"
    robert="robert"
    name(bob,robert)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the strings to quotes (either "bob" or 'bob').

So your call would be

```
name('bob', 'robert')
```

instead of

```
name(bob, robert)
```

.

If you use it without the quotes, python tries to find a variable with a name bob.

Also, you do not need to use the `str(first)` or `str(last)`  since both are already strings.